# Jetty upgrade 9.3.27 to 9.4.43 - build success but application deployment failed "Shared scheduler not started" error

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

My application currently runs on embedded jetty version 9.3.27 and we are trying to upgrade to 9.4.43. deployment step fails with "Shared scheduler not started" error

build tool : Gradle

- Using the default Session Manager:

```java
DefaultSessionIdManager defaultSessionIdManager = new DefaultSessionIdManager(server);
HouseKeeper houseKeeper = new HouseKeeper();
houseKeeper.setIntervalSec(30);
defaultSessionIdManager.setSessionHouseKeeper(houseKeeper);
server.setSessionIdManager(defaultSessionIdManager);
```

- Default SessionHandler:

```java
WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
SessionHandler sessions = webAppContext.getSessionHandler();
SessionCache cache = new DefaultSessionCache(sessions);
cache.setSessionDataStore(new NullSessionDataStore());
sessions.setSessionCache(cache);
```

build is successful but deployment step(/gradlew clean run) fails with following exception.

```
Exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Shared scheduler not started
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper.startScavenging(HouseKeeper.java:124)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper.setIntervalSec(HouseKeeper.java:206)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper.doStart(HouseKeeper.java:93)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager.doStart(DefaultSessionIdManager.java:346)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  There's not enough information to work with in your question.  Please edit the question and include more of your startup, in particular the `Server`, and its `setHandler` and when you call `server.start()`.   In the extremely limited view of your code it looks normal, but incomplete.

Comment: How (in your code) the deploy works is also important.

Comment: mind updating your question with the information requested?